# Hyperref: How to link not only a number of Definition/Theorem?

Tags: hyperref

Consider I am using hyperref package. Following LaTeX source:

```
By the definition of $G_{L,\lambda_1,\lambda_2}$ (Definition \ref{def:bipGraphInducedByLl1l2_DecomposesL}) we have that
```

produces the following output:

[image]

i.e., only the number of the definition is made to be hyperlink. Is there possibility to link also the keyword Definion? I mean, I want whole "Definition 4.3" to be a hyper link.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You could use the `cleveref` package with the `nameinlink` option.

Comment: You can adapt this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586692/237192

Comment: Thank you @Οὖτις, works great!